# C Pointers - Structs that are arrays

Tags: c, pointers

I have been working on this code for a few hours now and am confused as to why printf is only printing garbage, I am brand new to stack overflow and fairly new to C so please forgive me for any mistakes in this post. I researched for pointers to structs that are arrays and couldn't find anything helpful.

```
typedef struct my
{
    int x;
    int y;
} My;

My * main2(void);

void show(void)
{
    My * m = main2();

    printf("%u\n", m);

    printf("%u\n", m);
    printf("%d\n", m->x);
    printf("%d\n", m->y);
    m++;
    printf("%u\n", m);
    printf("%d\n", m->x);
    printf("%d\n", m->y);
    m++;
    printf("%u\n", m);
    printf("%d\n", m->x);
    printf("%d\n", m->y);
}

My * main2(void)
{
    My j[3];
    j[0].x = 2;
    j[0].y = 4;

    j[1].x = 3;
    j[1].y = 5;

    j[2].x = 7;
    j[2].y = 9;

    printf("%u\n", j);
    return j;
}

int main()
{
    show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable.

Comment: Which part is confusing you? The output of `j` from `main2()` or the output of the return value of `main2()` from `show()`?

Comment: Right but how do i get the value of that variable by passing the pointer to the address of my struct if my struct is an array?

Comment: The output of the show function is garbage data, that is confusing me.

Answer (score 4):

Variables defined inside a function only have the life-time of that function. Once the function returns, the variables in essence cease to exist.

Now, if you return a pointer to such a variable (or to the first element of an array like you do) and that data no longer exists, then you get [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you try to use the pointer.

One way to solve a problem like this is to pass the array (or, again, a pointer to its first element) as an *argument* to the function:

```
void main2(My *j)
{
    j[0].x = 2;
    // And so on...
}
```

And to pass an array to the function, remember that arrays *decays* to pointers to their first element when used in a context where a pointer is expected.

That means you could pass it like just about any other variable:

```
My arr[3];
main2(arr);  // equal to main2(&arr[0]);
```

---

On another note, the format to print a pointer using [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is `"%p"`. The pointer need to be casted `void *` as well:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) j);
```

Answer (score 2):

*why printf is only printing garbage ?* It's because of you are returning the address of a local variable here

```
My j[3];
...
...
return j; /* j is a local array, its scope is within this this function not outside */
```

your compiler could have warn you like this

> function returns address of local variable [-Werror=return-local-addr]

To overcome this, you can create dynamic array & return it.

Also while printing `m` which structure pointer, use `%p` instead of `%u` format specifier. for e.g

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got the answer, I forgot about this really really important everything in the function is "gone" after the function has returned, thank you to both of the people that helped answer this :)

```
typedef struct my
{
    int x;
    int y;
} My;

void getData(My * pos)
{
    printf("%d", pos->x);
    printf("%d", pos->y);
    pos++;
    printf("%d", pos->x);
    printf("%d", pos->y);
}

int main()
{
    My x[2];

    x[0].x = 3;
    x[0].y = 4;

    x[1].x = 5;
    x[1].y = 6;

    getData(x);

    return 0;
}
```